# Displaying datetime in laravel in the right format

Tags: php, laravel

I have a blog created with Laravel 5.5, In PostController and in Create function i have specified the time format for "Published_at" cloumn to 24 format, and it's inserted correctly into database with the right format

```
Nov 30, 2017 | 17:11:19
```

But when i try to display the time in post page i got this format

```
30, 11, 2017 | 1:51:29 pm
```

I don't know why, i have tried to use

```
date('M j,Y | H:i:s' ,strtotime($post->published_at))
```

solution but i got wrong date and time

```
Jan 1,1970 | 01:00:00
```

I hope the problem clearly described.
This is the code used to validate the date format in store function

```
'published_at' => [
            'required',
            'regex:/^[\d]{2},\s[\d]{2},\s[\d]{4}\s\|\s[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}$/',
        ],
```

And in create page the date display correctly

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="published_at" name="published_at" value="{{ old('published_at', date('M j, Y | G:i:s')) }}" autofocus>
```

But in Other pages when i use {{ $post->published_at }} or {{ $post->created_at }}... the time display in 12 format

Comment: what does `echo ($post->published_at);` return?

Comment: @musashii Return the correct datetime but with 12 format

Comment: Why not use Carbon?

Comment: What is your field type in database? Maybe show your migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated code**

```
echo DateTime::createFromFormat('d, m, Y \| h:i:s A', $post->published_at)->format('M j,Y | H:i:s');
```

Comment: Still the same problem with strtotime always display wrong date "Jan 1, 1970 | 01:00:00"

Comment: U have to notice that my timezone is "Europe/London"

Comment: Thanks @musashii for your solution, it's working now